# Хранение и использование данных типа String через указатели PChar

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-berlin

Проблема заключается в том, что данные на которые ссылаются указатели рандомным образом изменяются в течении работы приложения, несмотря на то что ни один поток не к ним не обращается.

Объявление указателей в классе:

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
...
private
  PStr1: PChar;
  PStr2: PChar;
  Pstr3: PChar;
...
```

Их инициализация:

```
constructor TTradeThread.Create(...);
begin
  ...
  PStr1 := PChar(SomeStringValue1);
  PStr2 := PChar(SomeStringValue2);
  ...
  PStr3 := PChar(SomeStringValue3);
  ...
end;
```

Все последующие обращения к указателям в моем коде производят только чтение данных: `StrBuf := String(PStr1)` и т.д.
При трассировке, нашел конкретные строки когда данные в указателях меняются и заполняются мусором. Например во время записи в файл `Writeln(TxtFile,'...')`, в стеке видно что указатель начинает отображать отрывок строки которая записывается в файл. Или после `idhttp1.Get('...')` - в указателе появляется отрывок заголовка HTTP запроса.
Из всего делаю вывод, что при инициализации `PStr1 := PChar(SomeStringValue1)` участок памяти никак не резервируется под хранение этих данных и по мере выполнения программы постоянно перезаписывается. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно инициализировать указатели что бы данные на которые они ссылаются не перезаписывались?

Comment: Кажется разобрался в чем причина. На самом деле инициализация указателя внутри потока в моем коде происходила следующим образом: `PStr1 := PChar(IntToStr(Self.IntValue));` Для наглядности и упрощения кода в приведенном мной примере, преобразование типа решил упустить. Но судя по всему моя проблема именно в этом и заключалась. В указатель попадала переменная Result из функции IntToStr, соответственно после выполнения функции эта область памяти и становилась невалидной. Прошу знатоков подтвердить правильность моего вывода.

Comment: Естественно, именно в этом и ошибка. Как я уже сказал в ответе - сохраняйте исходную строку и у вас не будет никаких проблем.

Comment: Возможно, вам будет интересно: http://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2009/09/pchars.html и http://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2009/09/blog-post.html

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо хранить сами строки, а не просто указатели на них. Потому как, после уничтожения строки, указатель становится невалидным.

Comment: Строки не уничтожаются. В реальном коде присвоение идет из компоненты `Edit1.Text`, сама компонента на всем протяжении исполнения программы не удаляется и не меняет свои свойства.

Comment: Если бы строки не уничтожались, указатели были бы валидными, а не мусорными, как у вас получается. Возможно вы в конструктор передаёте временные копии строк. Сохраните копии строк у себя в потоке и все проблемы уйдут.

Comment: @HeathRow если `SomeStringValue1` передается как один из параметров метода (в данном случае - конструктора), без модификатора const или var, то это - локальная копия строки, время жизни которой ограничено пределами этого метода. По выходу из метода память вернется менеджеру памяти. Используйте не PChar, а string, как вам уже дважды посоветовали. P.S. с модификаторами const или var - время жизни будет ограничено рамками того метода, где строка была сформирована.